# undefined variable and function on click is not working

Tags: jquery

I have problem in my jQuery code as shown below. I described here what we got problem in this.

```
var subnetCalculator = {
    _data: {
        _ipClass: $('#class_select'),
        _givenOctet1: $('#given_octet1_text'),
        _givenOctet2: $('#given_octet2_text'),
        _givenOctet3: $('#given_octet3_text'),
        _givenOctet4: $('#given_octet4_text'),
        _cidr: $('#given_mask_text')
    },
    initProblem: function(){
        var ipclass = this._data._ipClass.val();
        alert(ipclass); //ipclass variable is showing undefined.
    }
}

$("#problem_button").ready(function() { //This is not working on click function    
    console.log(5 + 6);
    subnetCalculator.initProblem();
});
```

Comment: Unable to replicate; your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wuq30h6u/. Check the console for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some problems are these:

1. You are not using doc ready block which ensures the elements are in DOM.
2. `ready` event is not `click` event.

---

Solution seems to me to wrap the code in doc ready block and instead of `ready` use `click` event:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var subnetCalculator = {
    _data: {
      _ipClass: $('#class_select'),
      _givenOctet1: $('#given_octet1_text'),
      _givenOctet2: $('#given_octet2_text'),
      _givenOctet3: $('#given_octet3_text'),
      _givenOctet4: $('#given_octet4_text'),
      _cidr: $('#given_mask_text')
    },
    initProblem: function() {
      var ipclass = this._data._ipClass.val();
      alert(ipclass); //ipclass variable is showing undefined.
    }
  }

  $("#problem_button").click(function() { // <------This should be "click"
    console.log(5 + 6);
    subnetCalculator.initProblem();
  });
});
```

Comment: Bro, Click is not working that's why I did ready there and I don't want to use of DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. You should bind the function to `click` event.

```
var subnetCalculator = {
  _data: {
    _ipClass: $('#class_select'),
    _givenOctet1: $('#given_octet1_text'),
    _givenOctet2: $('#given_octet2_text'),
    _givenOctet3: $('#given_octet3_text'),
    _givenOctet4: $('#given_octet4_text'),
    _cidr: $('#given_mask_text')
  },
  initProblem: function() {
    var ipclass = this._data._ipClass.val();
    alert(ipclass); * * //ipclass variable is showing undefined.**
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("#problem_button").click(function() {
    console.log(5 + 6);
    subnetCalculator.initProblem();

  });
});
```